# jQuery .now() not unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, unique

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8H4Y/).

```
obj = {};
obj[0] = 'hej';
obj[1] = 'hopp';

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    console.log($.now());
});
```

`$.now()` is the same number in the console.

How can I generate a unique number?

Comment: So your computer is too fast?

Comment: If you need a truly unique number, create a var that holds a number and increment it. No need to be fancy. You can even abstract that behind a function if you need it to be unique across the entire application and don't want a global count var.

Comment: You create an object, then gave it keys `0` and `1`. sounds more like an array to me.

Comment: You need a unique number or identifier (eg GUID)? If the second check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: @KevinB Simple and works great!

Comment: I don't know the format you need but use an UUID :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a counter which increments for each object. You could then add this counter to $.now() to make sure it's unique:

```
obj = {};
obj[0] = 'hej';
obj[1] = 'hopp';
counter=1;

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    console.log($.now() + counter);
    counter+=1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/):

> The $.now() method is a shorthand for the number returned by the
>   expression (new  Date).getTime().

So you basically use `new Date().getTime()`. However getTime() isn't accurate... Interresting quote from [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/):

> Effectively these browsers are only updating their internal getTime
>   representations every 15 milliseconds. This means that if you attempt
>   to query for an updated time it’ll always be rounded down to the last
>   time the timer was updated (which, on average, will have been about
>   7.5 milliseconds ago).

In short: `getTime()` isn't that accurate (in some browsers).

When you need a random number (as you do), use:

```
var randomVal = Math.random(); // e.g. 0.6137274974025786
var randomValI = Math.round(Math.random()*100000000000000000)  // e.g. 6137274974025786
```

When you need a more formal 'guid', use something like [this](http://guid.us/GUID/JavaScript):

```
function createGUID() {
    function S4() {
        return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1); 
    }

    // then to call it, plus stitch in '4' in the third group
    return (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0,3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
}
var guid = createGUID();
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.now()` isn't supposed to give you a unique number, just a " a number representing the current time" (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/). More specifically "the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

The simplest way to generate a unique identifier depends on the scope the identifier has to be unique in.

1: If the identifier just has to be unique within the scope of the function, a counter as suggested by SteveP would probably do the job best.

2: If the identifier needs to be unique within the scope of your application - and you do not have the possibility to keep track of the assigned identifiers (as in 1) - your job is more difficult.
In real-live applications such a scenario could be tackled by combining the timestamp with a random number, along the lines of

```
var identifier = $.now() + "_" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e10)
```

This approach doesn't guarantee for true uniqueness of `identifier` though since `Math.round(Math.random() * 1e10)` could return the same value twice in one millisecond. Depending on how often you generate a string like this, it will be still pretty unlikely you end up with the same string twice.

3: If you however aim for "uniqueness across space and time", you could get inspiration from http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

It should be noted that pure Javascript implementations like [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript#answer-2117523) only work with random numbers as well and will thus not generate *truly* unique identifiers. For a *truly* unique identifier across space and time a *truly* unique element such as a mac-address has to be used as part of the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Of course `$.now` just display the current timestamp. to have a random number use `Math.random()`

Comment: Yes, he cans use `key` for that. in a array it will be unique.