# randomly generate the unique id for the uploaded uploaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to generate the random id for the uploaded images with their file names.

my code is

```
var getUniqueMacroName = function(filename){
    var Name = $.trim(filename.replace(/.[^.]+$/,'').replace(/ /g, "").replace(/[^\w]|_/g, "").toUpperCase());
    var Ext = $.trim(filename.replace(/^.*\./,'').toUpperCase());
    var mac= _.map($("#data").DataTable().data(), function(a){return a[0]});

    var fileRand = Name.substring(0, (10 - fileExt.length));

    while(_.contains(mac, ("GM" + fileRand + fileExt))){
        var rand = Math.min(Math.floor((Math.random() * fileRand.length) + 5), (fileRand.length - 1));
        fileRand =  (fileRand.substring(0, rand) + rand + fileRand.substring(rand, fileRand.length)).substring(0, (10 - Ext.length));
    }
    return "GM" + fileRand + Ext;
}
```

If i upload the images like

1. gallery image 320 1.jpg
2. gallery image 320 2.jpg
3. gallery image 320 3.jpg
4. gallery image 320 4.jpg
5. gallery image 320 5.jpg
6. gallery image 320 6.jpg

the sixth image is execute infinite times in the while condition.This will happen when the uploaded image name have almost same.So the browser will be not respond.

Is there any way to generate the unique id for any type of file names(including the same filename) in javascript or jquery.

Comment: Yes you can use TimeStamp for unique. Date.now();

Comment: can you explain briefly?

Comment: it will generate miliseconds

Comment: You can also use UUIDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Editted by user suggestion** usefull answer;

Yes you can use TimeStamp for unique ID with `Date.now()`; It generate milliseconds and they are always unique;

> The now() method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a Number.

```
var getUniqueMacroName = function(filename){
    var Name = $.trim(filename.replace(/.[^.]+$/,'').replace(/ /g, "").replace(/[^\w]|_/g, "").toUpperCase());
    var Ext = $.trim(filename.replace(/^.*\./,'').toUpperCase());
    var mac= _.map($("#data").DataTable().data(), function(a){return a[0]});
    // dont need anymore control unique
    var fileRand = Date.getTime();
    fileRand = fileRand.substr(fileRand.length - 10);
    return "GM" + fileRand + Ext;
}
```

Comment: how can i restrict in 14 characters

Comment: fileRand = fileRand.substr(fileRand.length - 14); you can take last 14 id with it.

Comment: thank you @ hurricane. I solve this problem in another way using 
"new Date().getTime()".

Comment: @kalles Have a nice day.

Comment: Date.getTime() isn't unique. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523888/1183010).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach could work if you generate a longer 'random' number?

```
var random = Math.random()*100000000000000000;  // e.g. 6137274974025786
```

Comment: It's generate random number not unique number. If you use 10 number for random probability is 1/10. If you use 100000000000000000 number for random probability is 1/100000000000000000 so it's not a unique! If you use dateTime it's always count beacuse time always increase.

Comment: no, Date.getTime() is not unique (not always incrementing), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20523888/1183010).